# Problems with Magento Reindex (attributes)

Tags: mysql, magento, attributes, reindex

I have problems with reindex Magento CMS after integrate some products.

here is the LOG from the shell reindex

```
 /usr/home/sinusi/public_html/_duplicateshop/shell$ php indexer.php --status
```

> Product Attributes index process unknown error:
>   exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '32363-974-1-327' for key 'PRIMARY'' in /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
>   Stack trace:
>
> #0 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
>
> #1 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
>
> #2 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
>
> #3 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
>
> #4 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
>
> #5 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
>
> #6 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1998): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
>
> #7 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav/Source.php(280): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertArray('catalog_product...', Array, Array)
>
> #8 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav/Source.php(261): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Source->_saveIndexData(Array)
>
> #9 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav/Source.php(84): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Source->_prepareMultiselectIndex(NULL, NULL)
>
> #10 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav/Abstract.php(50): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Source->_prepareIndex()
>
> #11 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav.php(185): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Abstract->reindexAll()
>
> #12 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav->reindexAll()
>
> #13 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
>
> #14 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
>
> #15 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/shell/indexer.php(166): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
>
> #16 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/shell/indexer.php(212): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
>
> #17 {main}
>
> Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '32363-974-1-327' for key 'PRIMARY'' in /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
>   Stack trace:
>
> #0 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
>
> #1 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
>
> #2 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
>
> #3 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
>
> #4 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
>
> #5 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1998): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
>
> #6 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav/Source.php(280): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertArray('catalog_product...', Array, Array)
>
> #7 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav/Source.php(261): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Source->_saveIndexData(Array)
>
> #8 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav/Source.php(84): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Source->_prepareMultiselectIndex(NULL, NULL)
>
> #9 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav/Abstract.php(50): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Source->_prepareIndex()
>
> #10 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Indexer/Eav.php(185): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav_Abstract->reindexAll()
>
> #11 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Indexer_Eav->reindexAll()
>
> #12 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
>
> #13 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
>
> #14 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/shell/indexer.php(166): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
>
> #15 /usr/www/users/sinusi/_duplicateshop/shell/indexer.php(212): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
>
> #16 {main}

I have truncated `catalog_flats` and deleted the lock files
but error is still the same

Answer (score 0):

First, you can try to drop completely the flat tables as they will be recreated by the indexing process.

The fact that you reach a duplicate entry maybe means that an unique index have been removed from an origin table. Maybe a product attribute that must be unique as twice the same value in the database after human intervention straighly in the db.

If you can identify the field that is problematic, I can maybe extend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution provided in
http://www.magikcommerce.com/blog/how-to-resolve-magento-reindexing-errors-in-your-magento-store/#

Before run this method, Make sure to take the full back up of database.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - there was a duplicate entry in attribute

sorry for my question and thanks for your input!